# Scraping Issues

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get data from the following https://www.podchaser.com/lists/best-liberal-politics-podcasts-107a9FVaYE

There is no Captcha on the page but I am unable to scrape the data.  Here is out put of the soup I get.

```
<div class="cf-columns two">
<div class="cf-column">
<h2 data-translate="why_captcha_headline">Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?</h2>
<p data-translate="why_captcha_detail">Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary access to the web property.</p>
</div>
<div class="cf-column">
<h2 data-translate="resolve_captcha_headline">What can I do to prevent this in the future?</h2>
<p data-translate="resolve_captcha_antivirus">If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can run an anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not infected with malware.</p>
<p data-translate="resolve_captcha_network">If you are at an office or shared network, you can ask the network administrator to run a scan across the network looking for misconfigured or infected devices.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
<p class="text-13">
<span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">6ca95b9c3b3b7d82</strong></span>
<span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">•</span>
<span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Your IP</span>: 34.125.89.195</span>
<span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">•</span>
<span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
</p>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->
</div>
</div>
```

Not sure how to overcome this.  I know how to handle if there is a visible captcha.  Any ideas of how to scrape this webpage.

Comment: The website very clearly does not want you to do this. They provide an [API](https://features.podchaser.com/api/) and set restrictions in their [terms of service](https://www.podchaser.com/terms.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the 'User-Agent' header to pass that obstacle. Copying user agent value from the actual browser has helped in my case.

If you are using `requests`, you can set it like this:

```py
res = requests.get('https://www.podchaser.com/lists/best-liberal-politics-podcasts-107a9FVaYE',
                   headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 ...'})
```